# Setting up Breaks in itemize Environment

Tags: page-breaking, itemize

I have multiple large itemize environments where a general ones looks like

```
\subsection*{Page }
\begin{itemize}
     \item
     \hfill
     \begin{tcolorbox}
          \blindtext
     \end{tcolorbox}
     \blindtext
\end{itemize}
```

The problem I am having is that there exist breaks like the following:
[image]
[image]

The corresponding code is

```
\item 
    \hfill
    \begin{tcolorbox}
        \ldots for $dK \pm Kd$ maps closed forms to exact forms \ldots
    \end{tcolorbox}
    We check that $dK \pm Kd$ takes closed forms to exact forms. If $\o$ is a closed form then $d\o = 0$, and
    $$(dK \pm Kd)(\o) = dK\o \pm Kd\o = dK\o.$$
    The form $dK\o$ is exact because it's the image of $K\o$ under $d$.
```

and

```
    \subsubsection*{Page 16}
\begin{itemize}
    \item
    \hfill
    \begin{tcolorbox}
    \begin{center}
        $\displaystyle H^{q} = \begin{cases} \R & q = 0 \\ 0 & q > 0 \end{cases}$
    \end{center}
    \end{tcolorbox}
    $H^{q}$ means $H^{q}(\R^{0})$ where $\R^{0}$ is the one point space. Notice that we have no local coordinates in this case.
```

I would like to have a setup in the preamble to stop breaks like this and move the entire note to the next page. Is this possible?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Could you please extend your code to a full example document that shows the problem you encouter? I don't understand what exactly is the question here. I thought it would be a breaking tcolorbox, but these boxes don't break across pages by default.

Comment: @siracusa Thank you, I have edited my post in the hope that my question is more clear!

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Please make your code snippet compilable. That is called a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is with the line break before the `tcolorbox`.  If you reduce the width and use `\centering` rather than the `center` environment, then the box stays on the same line as the bullet point.  I am not sure what vertical positioning you want; a suggestion is given below.

[image: Sample output]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tcolorbox,amsmath,amssymb}

\newcommand{\R}{\mathbb{R}}

\begin{document}

\subsubsection*{Page 16}
\begin{itemize}
\item
  \begin{tcolorbox}[width=\linewidth,baseline=\tcbtextheight+\baselineskip]
    \centering
    $\displaystyle H^{q} =
    \begin{cases}
      \R, & q = 0, \\
      0, & q > 0.
    \end{cases}$
  \end{tcolorbox}
  $H^{q}$ means $H^{q}(\R^{0})$ where $\R^{0}$ is the one point
  space. Notice that we have no local coordinates in this case.
\end{itemize}

\end{document}
```

You might want to look at the `tcbitemize` environment, which may better suit your purposes.

Comment: This perfectly resolves my issue! Thank you very much.